Merits of derived geometry
What are the merits of derived geometry? More precisely, which specific mathematical problems that can be formulated without this machinery have been solved using it? If those problems exist, could they have been solved without derived geometry?

The merit of derived algebraic geometry is existence of large amount of interesting questions which could not be formulated without it.

In this paper, Bhatt uses derived techniques to prove some nice results, such as this: Every quasicompact, quasiseparated scheme (or even algebraic space) $X$, viewed as a functor on rings, commutes with arbitrary products.

Does this answer your question? Applications of derived categories to "Traditional Algebraic Geometry"

@Chow: Of course not.

@Denis T: I am pretty sure that the question of how many angels can sit comfortably on the tip of a needle is interesting and not well understood for centuries (the answer probably involves Conway's surreal numbers!). I am also pretty sure that it is scientifically irrelevant.
